# AframeVR Aframe Oculus Go replicate controller functions from altspace vr app

Tags: aframe, webvr, oculusgo, webxr

I want to replicate the controller functions in the Altspace VR Oculus Go app.

How do I make it so that the Oculus Go controller trigger is a click, at the same time pressing up on the trackpad triggers an arc teleport, touching left or right on the touch pad triggers a right turn or left turn, touching down on the track pad triggers a backwards movement, and tapping the back button triggers a menu with an option to escape webvr mode in the Oculus Browser.

Please try the app for additional clarity about what I would like to accomplish.

Comment: I noticed that its possible to create a listener for trackpad changed, a starting point to customize trackpad?

I would like to customize the trackpad for different apps and different events, so like maybe pressing down opens a menu instead of a back button, and in this menu then a left or right swipe would help navigate this menu, a downswipe could be different from a down press and could create a back movement. Right now virtual keyboards use the laser pointer and the trigger to click keys, but the VR keyboard could be a lot faster if the trackpad is used to select letters.

Comment: This is a great example of a developer using the Oculus Go touch pad in an excellent way. I am just sharing this as a starting point to figuring out how I can write the controller I want to make.
https://crystalis-vr.glitch.me/